# Como fazer o Drag de uma imagem sem jQuery

Tags: javascript, drag-n-drop

Gostaria de fazer o usuário poder arrastar a imagem quando clicar nela, porém sem utilizar o jquery para isso, usando o JavaScript puro. Consigo pegar a posição do mouse na tela, porém não estou conseguindo fazer a função para a imagem ser arrastada. Poderiam me ajudar ?

Aqui o meu fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/r4sj5218/

Comment: Qual seria o problema em usar jquery?

Comment: Gostaria de melhorar meu conhecimento em javascript, e o framework não enriquece tanto assim o conhecimento... Não queria usar algo que não sei como fazer, entende?

Comment: Entendo perfeitamente! Acho que todo bom desenvolvedor já pensou assim um dia! Mas, acho que hoje é quase impossível utilizar javascript sem utilizar o jquery. Acho sua atitude muito legal, mas tentar reinventar a roda, pode atrasar um pouco seu processo.

Comment: Compreendo, na verdade eu concordo, eu tive de utilizar isso num projeto e usei o jQuery, agora resolvi fazer os testes só em JavaScript pois agora que já
terminei estou "sem pressa", digamos assim. Por puro aprendizado mesmo!

Comment: @MichelSimões **quase impossível utilizar javascript sem utilizar o jquery**, discordo; **tentar reinventar a roda, pode atrasar um pouco seu processo.** concordo, em termos :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiz uma implementação simples utilizando os eventos `mouse*`, para detectar o clique, o arraste e quando solta a imagem. Neste último evento, a *position* da imagem é atualizada com a posição do *mouse*. Dá para aprimorar, mas já é um começo. Testado no Chrome e Firefox.

```js
var img = document.querySelector("#img");
img.ondragstart = function() { return false; };

function dropImage(e) {
  img.style.top = e.clientY + 'px';
  img.style.left = e.clientX + 'px';
}

function drop(e) {
  dropImage(e);
  document.removeEventListener("mousemove", dropImage);
  document.removeEventListener("mouseup", drop);
}

img.addEventListener("mousedown", function(){
  document.addEventListener("mousemove", dropImage);
  document.addEventListener("mouseup", drop);
});
```

```css
#img {
  width: 25%;
  position: absolute;
}

#img:hover {
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
  cursor: grab;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://gabrielozzy.com/site-amor/img/slide_1.jpg" id="img" />
```

Comment: Resposta excelente ! Obrigado !

Comment: Fiquei apenas com uma dúvida. Porque o return false no img.ondragstart ?

Comment: Pra não realizar o arraste padrão do navegador. Tava tendo um comportamento estranho no Firefox

Comment: Entendido, obrigado !